# Swift – ARMeshAnchor to Data conversion

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

In my project I'm trying to store an ARMeshAnchor into UserdDefaluts converting it to Data. I'm unable to find a solution.

This one of my errors
Instance method `encode(_:forKey:)` requires that `ARMeshAnchor` conform to `Encodable`.

Maybe it is better to convert them to an SCNNode and try to convert the node to Data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you should use `NSKeyedArchiver` class and your code might look like this:

```
@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

fileprivate func convertMeshAnchors() -> UserDefaults {

    guard let frame = arView.session.currentFrame else { return }
    let meshAnchors = frame.anchors.compactMap { $0 as? ARMeshAnchor }

    let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: meshAnchors,
                                          requiringSecureCoding: false)

    let savedAnchors = UserDefaults.standard
    savedAnchors.set(data, forKey: "MeshAnchors")
    savedAnchors.synchronize()

    return savedAnchors
}
```

And remember in RealityKit there's also a scene object where anchors' collection is located:

```
arView.scene.anchors
```

Comment: I think that `requiringSecureCoding` parameter should be `false` due to `ARAnchor.supportsSecureCoding` also returns `false`.